# Android show dialog alert not exit screen after press OK

Tags: android

I have developed a show dialog alert box in a fragment. After pressing the OK button in the box, It does not exits the screen. The show dialog alert keeps prompting on the screen. I don't want to quit the app after pressing OK, but I want it to go back to the HomeScreen. How to make sure that show dialog alert box will exit the screen after pressing OK?

Here is the code

```
    public class FavouriteListFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_ITEM_ID = "favorite_list";
    private SharedPreference sharedPreference;
    private StaggeredGridView mStaggeredView;
    TextView tv;
    ImageView iv;
    String text;
    String favouriteUrl;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favourite_staggeredgridview, container, false);
        mStaggeredView = (StaggeredGridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.staggeredview);
        mStaggeredView.setOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
        sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();

       // iv=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        text = sharedPreference.getValue(getActivity());

        sharedPreference.saveFavourite(getActivity(), text);

        String[] photoUrl;
        photoUrl = new String[10];

        if(photoUrl==null){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"no favourite list",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            showAlert(getResources().getString(R.string.no_favorites_items),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.no_favorites_msg));
        } else {
            if (photoUrl.length == 0) {
                showAlert(
                        getResources().getString(R.string.no_favorites_items),
                        getResources().getString(R.string.no_favorites_msg));
            }
        }

        for (int index = 0; index < photoUrl.length; index++) {

            photoUrl[index]=text;
            if(text==null){
                showAlert(
                        getResources().getString(R.string.no_favorites_items),
                        getResources().getString(R.string.no_favorites_msg));
            }
            else {
                StaggeredGridViewItem item;
                item = new FavouriteGridItem(getActivity(), photoUrl); //pass one image of index
                mStaggeredView.addItem(item);
            }
        }

//        URL url = null;
//        try {
//            url = new URL(text);
//        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
//        Bitmap bmp = null;
//        try {
//            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
//        } catch (IOException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
//        iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        return rootView;

    }

    private void showAlert(String string, String message) {

        if (getActivity() != null && !getActivity().isFinishing()) {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .create();
            alertDialog.setMessage(message);
            alertDialog.setCancelable(false);

            // setting OK Button
            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            //getActivity().finish();
                            getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
                        }
                    });
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }

    private StaggeredGridView.OnScrollListener scrollListener = new StaggeredGridView.OnScrollListener() {
        public void onTop() {
        }

        public void onScroll() {

        }

        public void onBottom() {

        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have this `getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();`

Comment: where you used this alertdialog function.may be after calling this function you call to quit fragment.

Comment: @Raghunandan Take a look at this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStackImmediate() - I guess he's trying to emulate a back press, but I think the issue is somewhere else in the code then in the snippet above

Comment: @anthonymonori i know that. i am asking why is that in onClick??

Comment: @Raghunandan, The reason i used popBackStackImmediate() is because I want to pop back homescreen fragment after click OK

Comment: @Vishwa, i have attached the full code above...need your advise..thank you!

Comment: @michelletbs the main reason for alert keeps prompting is you declared an string array with 10.after that for loop executes the alert dialog function upto 10 times.so that your getting alert dialog rapidly.Second think is The proper for  moving from one fragment to another fragment is by using interface.Sometimes OS may clear stack at some critical suitations.when you trying to get fragment from stack it is possible to exit application in some times